# Regex for email validation

Tags: regular-expressions

I have created a regex for email validation which will check the email is in proper format or not.

Regular expression for the email is

> [a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}[.]{0,1}[a-zA-Z]{0,2}

but when i am putting an email address like shantanu0076@abc.abcedf.com

this regex expression is not working

How can i solve this issue

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/j1cEWk/1 i encourage you to test more.

Answer (score 3):

Your regular expression doesn't do what you think it does. `.`, by itself, matches any character, not just a `.`. You need to escape it to specify a literal period. Also, note that emails are a lot more complicated than you think they are; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378) for a current regular expression that should match all possible valid emails. Translated to Apex, it looks like:

```
static Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile('(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])');
public static Boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    return emailPattern.matcher(email).matches();
}
```